# How can I get a count of how many times a distinct value appears in a column?

Tags: sql

How can I find out how many times each distinct value appears in a column?

**NOTE: This is not a case of "how do I find distinct values in a column?"**

For example, this column contains five values:

```
Col1
AA
AA
AB
AC
AD
AA
AC
AE
```

Which query can I run that would result in: the following?

```
AA: 3
AB: 1
AC: 2
AD: 1
AE: 1
```

So far I can only get the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Col1))
FROM table1

Result: 5
```

I have tried different variations of it but get the same result each time.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. Simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT Col1)` to make code clearer. (However, you don't want COUNT DISTINCT here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
select col1, count(*)
from table1
group by col1;
```